# IndexOf n-th character of that type

Tags: c#, indexof

I need to get the index of the n-th character of that type in a string.

Example:

```
string test = "asdfasdfasdf";
int index = test.IndexOf("a", 3);
```

and `index` would be 8, since the 3rd a has the index of 8

Is there a function that does that or do you have any idea how to do that in a smart way?

Comment: You can do it in a few lines of code with a counter and a for loop.

Comment: @itsme86 yeah, I probably can, but I'm asking whether there's a one-liner for that. basically just curiosity

Comment: @itsme86 okay, thanks.

Comment: You will have to use a different name for that method as [there already is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) an overload with that signature.

Comment: @lenny so how do you figure the `index` to be `8` when you are telling it to start a position `3` which would yield `4` without even running the code.. come on now..?

Comment: @RenéVogt @MethodMan I didn't even know about that overload. The `3` is supposed to tell the functon that it's supposed to look for the 3rd a in the string

Comment: You could implement as a class extension of string, then at least the usage would be a one liner. Look up class extensions to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop will do the trick, but you can place the for loop in an **extension method** to get this functionality as a one-liner throughout your application.

Like this:

```
public static int NthIndexOf(this string text, char letter, int occurrence)
{
    if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));

    int count = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < text.Length; index++)
        if (text[index] == letter)
        {
            if (++count == occurrence)
                return index;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

Usage:

```
string test = "asdfasdfasdf";
int index = test.IndexOf('a', 3);
```

Comment: can you make the answer complete by adding some code?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single line, but it is not pretty:

```
var s = "aabbabhjhjdsfbaxt";
var idx = s.Select((c, i) => new {c, i})
    .Where(p => p.c == 'a')
    .Skip(2)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.i ?? -1;
```

The idea is to pair up characters with their indexes, filter by character, skip n-1 items, and take the next one if it exists.

Another approach would be to use regex with look-behind:

```
var idx = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=(a[^a]*){2})a").Index;
```

This matches an `'a'` preceded by two more `'a'`s, possibly with other characters in the middle.

Comment: I'd use `.FirstOrDefault()?.i ?? -1` to be aligned with `IndexOf()`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride That's an excellent idea, thank you very much!

Comment: Oh how I like to play around with linq and create such funny little queries.. but I think it's definitly a really bad solution for the given problem considering memory usage and performance, especially for a string operation. Don't know what OP needs this for, but since it would (hopefully) be wrapped into an extension anyway, one should stick to simple loops or existing string operations (e.g. concat `IndexOf('a', i)` calls).

Comment: @RenéVogt I agree - to quote Dijkstra, "I don't like [cracking an egg with a sledgehammer] no matter how effective a sledgehammer may be for cracking eggs." The first solution is no more than a demonstration of how this could be done with a shiny new sledgehammer of LINQ, not something that one should do in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method for this like that:

```
public static int NthIndexOf(this string s, char c, int occurence)
{
    if (s == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
    if (occurence <= 0) return -1;

    int i = -1, o = 0;
    do
    {
        i = s.IndexOf(c, i+1);
        o++;
    } while (i >= 0 && o < occurence);

    return i;
}
```

After checking the input arguments it consecutivly uses [`string.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the n-th index of the desired character `c`.
If no further occurence of `c` is found (`IndexOf` returns `-1`) the loop breaks.

---

Usage:

```
string test = "asdfasdfasdf";
int index = test.NthIndexOf('a', 3); // 8
```

---

Of course you can do the same with a parameter of type `string` for `c` instead of `char`, but would need to change `s.IndexOf(c, i+1)` to `s.IndexOf(c, i+c.Length)`.

Comment: That is a very nice solution. What's the difference between a `while() { }` and a `do { } while()` loop?

Comment: @lenny The difference is that `while` tests the condition _before_ the loop's body and `do while` tests it at the end of the loop's body. Since I need to initialize `i` but test the result of `IndexOf`, I choose `do while` because it tests `i` after the first call to `IndexOf` instead of before that.

Answer (score 0):

As René Vogt said you should use an extension method chaining calls to `IndexOf()` for performance reasons:

```
public static int NthIndexOf(this string s, string value, int n)
{
    var index = -1;

    for (; n > 0; n--)
        index = s.IndexOf(value, index + 1);

    return index;
}
```

This returns the 0-based start index of the (1-based) `n`th occurence of the string `value`.

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xlqf2B